# Inflate within Recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm beginner in Kotlin so I need some help. I’m using a recyclerview to inflate “one_row_layout”. It works well, and shows aroun 10 rows of “one_row_layout” inside the recyclerview.

So, when I click this one “one_row_layout” view, I want to open(inflate) another “full_screen_layout”. The thing is here, “full_screen_layout” should be seen full screen, not inside of recyclerview.

I couldn’t figured it out how I can do that. Any idea?
Thanks.

[Intent not recognizable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUCWJ.png)

Comment: are you wanting to navigate to another activity to open up that screen?

Comment: I'm not sure if a new acitivty needed? If it's needed, ok, I can go with that way. Is it possible to do on the same activity?

Comment: it is, but I personally wouldn't. If you're going to click on a row and show completely new content on the entire screen, I'd just navigate to a different screen.

Comment: Thanks for the method. I'm trying with "
val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)  -  
startActivity(intent)" 
command but somehow "Intent" doesn't recognizable. It can recognizable in main acitivity. Why is that? Just added the Android Studio's warning message to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to have the responsibility for navigating to another "layout" inside of a recyclerView.  Instead pass your adapter an onClick method so that your fragment can do that work.

So something like:

```
class YourAdapter(
        private val onClick: (item: <InsertYourDataClassHere>) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>()

...
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { 
            onClick(...)
        }
    }
...
```

Then in your Fragment where you are instantiating your adapter you can just pass it the data it needs to render your new layout in another fragment.

```
val adapter = YourAdapter {
   // Navigate to DetailFragment here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omega, just added a comment about your post.

Comment: @sleepy it works so can you press the check mark so it would show that his answer is correct? This is to help other people who also need this. Thanks